# React Native (Expo) - Firebase Auth / 'Sign In' works when run in 'Web browser' but times out in real device

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, metro-bundler

I'm having a problem with Firebase Auth in my React Native (expo) app.

I managed to code a register/login system that works perfectly when I run it using Metro Bundler "Run in web browser" option, but when I try to run it in my real device ('Expo Go' QR scan) the "signInWithEmailAndPassword" function seems to time out.

After 60 seconds of pressing "Sign In" button an error is thrown "Firebase: Error (auth/timeout)"

Does anyone know why is this happening or what can I do to test my app in my real device?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for it ?

Comment: I did not find a solution. But if it means anything to you: I already deployed my app and it is working just as expected. So I couldn't test on real mobile device but the web testing was sufficient. I guess it's a problem with 'Expo Go' app.